# Formula (TRUE or FALSE) returning whether a 10 numbers list contains given number in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I receive every day `10` aleatory numbers, from `1` to `20`, which I put in Excel to cells from `A1` to `A10`. I want to make a formula that shows me, in `B1` cell, if a number (let’s say `2`) is in those `10` numbers. If it is, the result should be `True`, otherwise `False`.

I searched all the web and I didn't find a solution for this apparently simple problem. I tried every formula I found but nothing worked.

Thanks everybody for your quick replies.
I wish you all the best.
Tha answer that worked was =COUNTIF(A1:A10;2)>0. So simple :)

Comment: Can you post a sample of one of your numbers and the result you are expecting please?

Comment: let`s say i have numbers from A1 to A10: 1 2 5 8 9 10 11 13 15 19. I want to see automaticly after i put these numbers, on other cell, lets say B1, if number 2 is in these 10 numbers, to show me True, or False if it not. So in thise case, in B1 it shoudl appear True. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10;2)>0
```

or

```
=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(2;A1:A10;0)))
```

Comment: +1 I'd prefer the MATCH one really, since COUNTIF can be much slower on bigger datasets.

Comment: @Jerry, thanks, it's true, but OP mentioned that range contains only 10 numbers:)

Comment: Yes, I know, was just mentioning it because the question is on the web and anyone could find the question and try the answers, and they might not be in the same exact situation :)

Comment: try to change `,` to `;` like this: `=COUNTIF(A1:A10;2)>0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use one function less with:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(2,A1:A10,0))
```

Since we know that `MATCH` returns either a number, or an error.